# Variable is undefined while trying to GET it from server

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got a strange warning when i try to get the value from my object. The value i get is in JSON. I wonder what is the problem here, what is wrong with my code. Why do i get undefined on my variable ?

My template code:

```
<template>
    <textarea id="terms" v-model="terms.value" name="terms" type="text" rows="20"></textarea>
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light " v-on:click="updateUserProfile">Update Profile</button>
</template>


    <script>
    import firebase from 'firebase'
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {

        data: function() {
            return {
              id: '',
              email: '',
              terms: {},

            }
        },
        methods: {
            getUserProfile: function() {
                var accessToken;
                var self = this;
                    var config = {
                      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}
                    };
                    axios.get('https://api-link/', config).
                    then(response => {
                        console.log("Response on GET OK: " + response)
                        self.id = response.data.id
                        self.terms = response.data.terms

                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                      console.log("Error on GET: " + e)
                    });
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error on getting token: " + error)
                });
            },
            updateUserProfile: function() {
              var accessToken;
                var self = this;
                var config = {
                  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}
                };
                axios.put('https://api-link/',
                { 
                  terms: self.terms
                }, config).
                then(response => {
                    console.log("Response on PUT: " + response)
                    self.email = response.data.email
                    self.id = response.data.id
                    self.userType = response.data.user_type
                    self.terms = response.data.terms
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  console.log("Error on PUT: " + e)
                });

            },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getUserProfile()
        },
    }
    </script>
```

Below is my screenshot from my console, pls comment if you need more information.
Really appreciate the help, cuz I'm stuck here for hours. also to mention I'm a newbie in VueJS
[image]

Comment: Which line of code is the problem at?

Comment: I think it's on Getting the terms value, on my getUserProfile()

Comment: One issue is that you have two root elements in your template. You need to contain the `textarea` and `button` in some containing tag like a `div`.

Comment: Here is your code cleaned up a bit (your component is in App.vue). https://codesandbox.io/s/jv5365839y

Comment: i see that you added `v-if="terms"` , that will display if there is a value, but i need the same input for updating or if the user don't want to set terms it will be empty

Comment: Then, you should initialize `terms.value` in your data function (as in `terms: {value: ''}`) See the updated sandbox.

Comment: This doesn't work, i get the same warning `_vm.terms is undefined"`

Comment: How to do a validation, to check first if its undefined then fill it with something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your response is at first undefined, if not then you can assign your response data to your variable:
Put this in your GET, and i think this will remove the warning/error.

```
if (response.data.terms !== undefined) {
    self.terms = response.data.terms
}
```